# Using jQuery UI datepicker in Lotus Domino - prev/next disappeared

Tags: jquery, lotus-domino, lotus

I'm developing a Lotus Domino app that uses jQuery's datepicker. When I reference the jQuery code from code.jquery.com, I can see the prev and next arrows at the top of the calendar, but when I download this code from the site, put it in my NSF file, and reference it from there, the arrow graphics disappear.  The calendar still works, and when I hover where prev and next should appear, I can see the title text.  Just no graphics.  Ideas?

```
Heading code:
<style type="text/css">
pre { display:none; }
#ui-datepicker-div, .ui-datepicker { font-size: 75%; }
.calContainer{ margin: 0 0 0 0; }
.clear{ clear: both; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="svr/file.nsf/css/jquery-ui.css"; />
<script type="text/javascript" src="svr/file.nsf/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript" src="svr/file.nsf/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>;
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
   $('.calContainer > pre').each(function(i){
     eval($(this).text());
   });
});
</script>

Body code:
<div class="calContainer">
[HCTDate] <---- Notes field defined as Text, Editable
<pre>
$('#HCTDate').datepicker({ });
</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: your HTML and script will help to answer you... just reading your post... and guessing.. what you might have done wrong... is not a way to ask questions....

Comment: Heading code:
<style type="text/css">
pre { display:none; }
#ui-datepicker-div, .ui-datepicker{ font-size: 75%; }
.calContainer{ margin: 0 0 0 0; }
.clear{ clear: both; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://svr/file.nsf/css/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svr/file.nsf/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://svr/file.nsf/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.calContainer > pre').each(function(i){
    eval($(this).text());
   });
 });
</script>

Comment: Body code:
<div class="calContainer">
[HCTDate]   <---- Notes field defined as Text, Editable
<pre>
        $('#HCTDate').datepicker({
        });
</pre>
</div>

Comment: better add the code to question than in comments

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you also added the image files to your .NSF and that the paths are correct.

Answer (score 0):

download the jquery-ui zip file for the theme and extract it to the domino/html folder. 
put your link as

```
"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/jquery-ui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css\"/>"
```