# How to display date picker for field with date/time type in web

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have form with a field in `Lotus Notes` where I display `date/time field` using `Native OS` style.

So when edit in `Lotus Notes` for this field, it will displayed date picker. 
I also have a similar form with `Lotus Notes` but for Browser but using `HTML` and `Notes`.

All field in Browser form are similar to `Lotus Notes`. 
So when I try to display the field for `Date/Time`, it do not display date picker in web, instead just display text field.

#### How can I show date picker for `Date/Time field` in Browser?

Any help I appreaciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a decent css/js framework for this, like bootstrap. maybe this helps [Using jQuery UI datepicker in Lotus Domino - prev/next disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16652278/using-jquery-ui-datepicker-in-lotus-domino-prev-next-disappeared)

Comment: Ah, so there is no default function and I still need to use as you suggest. Okay will refer to it. Thanks!

Comment: There's a default date picker if you are using xpages.

Comment: Right now I am using classic web application. I will look into xpages after this project is done. By the way, may I know, where should I put the downloaded jQuery file?

Comment: I would put it in the Webcontent folder (package explorer), then you can reference the files relative to .nsf/

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit loss. Never done this. Where is exactly Webcontent folder? Do you mean File Resource?

Comment: in the designer, goto  Window -> show eclipse views -> Package explorer, look and expand your nsf, there you have a webcontent folder. Import the jquery, js or css into this folder (Right click on webcontent, select general\File system). Now you can import the same folder structure as your js/css framework

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I found the WebContent. But there is no general\File system. Should I create one first?

Comment: Hi @Umeli . I has insert into my WebContent. So how can I called the link for it in my html header?

Comment: You can address relative to your .nsf. like src="/pathToNsf/superdb.nsf/js/jquery.min.js" if your webcontent folder contains the file js/jquery.min.js. Or you can try to address them relative to your form probably somehting like src="js/jsquery.min.js"